# 117/5000 Uploaded file to public_html in cpanel

Tags: laravel

I tried uploading the first laravel projet in cpanel, when uploading image files can't enter public_html as I marked red, and I have changed the index.php file as shown below.

[cPanel public_html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3bkt.png)

[index.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ku8Le.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should use Composer (and git) to deploy your project. Here's a guide that works well for shared hosting: https://github.com/petehouston/laravel-deploy-on-shared-hosting